# How do I add 'www' before a subdomain, like www.subdomain.domain.com?

Tags: subdomain, domain-registration

I want to add `www` in front of a subdomain e.g. `www.subdomain.domain.com`.

My blogs are hosted on Blogger and am using GoDaddy for having custom domains.

I have HOST @ entries for 'domain' pointing specified by blogger. The following subsdomains are configured by adding CNAME alias as follows:

```
subdomain -> ghs.google.com
www -> ghs.google.com
```

For `domain` (including `www.domain`) I have one blog. 
For `subdomain`, I am pointing it to seperate blog using above entries and `subdomain.domain.com` works fine.

I read articles on this issue and tried adding following CNAME entry but no luck:

```
www.subdomain  ->  subdomain.domain.com
```

How do I make `www.subdomain.domain.com` work ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this "arrow" `->` syntax you're using but a CNAME record should point to an A record, not another CNAME: `www.subdomain.domain.com CNAME ghs.google.com`

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned GoDaddy the subdomains there can be managed using web control panel - 
as enabled using Hosted Domains link in the menu using Add Subdomain link, [see more here support.godaddy.com](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4652/managing-your-hosting-account-subdomains)

Answer (score 1):

Blogger can’t use two domains for the same blog. On a subdomain, it will read the `www.` differently than with a regular domain. It reads the `www.` as another separate domain, while on a second level domain, the `www.` will be included as one you can use. In fact, Blogger can’t host blogs on naked domains, so on a regular domain, they automatically go to the `www.` subdomain to host it on  as if it’s just the main website and have the naked domain redirect to the `www.` version.

Your records should be for `subdomain` and `www.subdomain`, not just `www`, unless you are already in the DNS zone for the subdomain. If you put those records in the DNS zone for your domain, and it doesn’t work, it ain’t gonna.